# make 4 window video conference and cannot be drag

Tags: jakarta-ee

how to make 4 window video conference and make it cannot be drag? i already change the code in commonVideoViewContentSWF10.lzx but  i can't make it to 4 video conference. thanks before

```
<method name="getNewVideoObjectByPos" args="publicSID">
    <![CDATA[
        var obj = this.getVideoObjectByPublicSID(publicSID);
        if (obj!=null){
            return obj;
        }

        //Get a Free VideoView Slot
        var freePos = this.getVideoObjectFreePos(40, 396, 360);


        return new lz.videoObjectPlayBroadcast(this,{
                publicSID:publicSID,
                width:videoWidth,
                height:videoHeight,
                x:freePos[0],
                y:freePos[1],
                isInterview:canvas.isInterview

            });

    ]]>
</method>
```